# Creating irregular shapes for a jigsaw puzzle game in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to make a jigsaw puzzle in flash. I know how to create square kind of shapes. But I want to create this kind of irregular shapes. See the live demo of puzzles in the links shown

http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/jigsawpuzzle/preview/4952.html
http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/whitejigsaw/whitejigsaw.html

I just want to how to create the irregular shapes.

Does anyone know or can anybody give useful links as to how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My ideas:

- Shapes can be just Bitmaps, masked by irregular filled Shape. Each piece of puzzle has shared BitmapData. Shapes can be created by series of `drawRect/drawEllipse/curveTo` calls in fill mode.
- Watch their relative positions to catch the moment when they should 'snap' together. Also cull combinations not close to each other.

Comment: Watching relative positions seems pointless to me. Just store the solution position for each piece and check against that; no need to check the position of pieces relative to each other.

Comment: This means shapes must be placed on predefined coords to snap. Usually they can be snapped to each other in any area (and then moved together to their final position) - this requires relative positions (or I misunderstood you?)

Comment: That's true. I guess it depends on exactly how you want the puzzle to behave; I wouldn't want pieces to snap together unless they were in the correct final positions, but I also hadn't seen the example he linked and it behaves the way you described.

Comment: Actually wait, the first example he linked works your way; the second works they way I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your shapes dynamically with code, try using the `graphics.curveTo()` method. This can be used in combination with `graphics.lineTo()` to make the outline for your pieces.

You could also make your pieces using the pen tool within the Flash IDE to create movie clips that can my used for creating object instances to be used as masks for your puzzle. This works if you plan on having the same puzzle layouts more than once.

Answer (score 1):

That's done using masking: http://www.flash-here.com/tutorials/flash_masking.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the following:

http://www.sephiroth.it/file_detail.php?id=111#

A little bit old.

Comment: I cannot follow it. I do not have AS2 background. Can you tell me the basic idea. Thanks for considering my question.